# How to convert pdf files to doc file in android?

Tags: android, pdf, edit

I have a problem in editing the pdf file. I have used pdfParser class with the help of this i can view the pdf file very easily. Now i want to edit the pdf file how can i do this. which jar files are supported for this. I have used the pdfBox jar file for this but it shows an exception for PDDocument class.

Thanks

Comment: i also used itext library but in that there is no solution to edit the pdf file. I also used pdfbox but in that PDDocument class not working. Is there any other jar file which i used to edit the pdf file?

Comment: Have you figured out a way to do it. IF so please mention it as I am in the same boat as you now

Answer (score 0):

There are several Java Open-Source projects that let you convert between several file formats. You can try Jasper Reports or one of Apache POI.